# Boot only with usb cable energy

Tags: boot, power, power-supply, usb-power

My raspberry worked fine with a 5V-2A charger.
From few days, It boots only with the energy coming from the USB cable from my computer.
If I use the usual charger, it goes in a boot loop, displaying the colored screen and rebooting itself.
I tried with different charger (5V-2A) and the result is the same.
Why is this happening? What charger should I buy?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi used to boot from a charger.  The Pi no longer boots from that charger.  The charger is failing, you need to buy a new one.

The Pi doesn't boot from a different charger which claims to be 5V at 2 amp.  That charger is no good, you need to buy a new one.

Are you sure you haven't added something to the Pi (e.g. a new screen) which has increased the power requirements?

Comment: Yes, the pi isn't plugged with anything. Shouldn't the energy from the USB cable be lower than the one from the power supply?

Comment: @Camilla8 Your experience suggests otherwise.  Are you connecting the chargers and the USB cable via the microUSB port on the Pi?

Comment: Computer USB --- Raspberry Micro USB

Answer (score 0):

Well, bad USB cables and chargers (by bad I mean cheap, straight) will not work with the Pi (at least from my experience with Pi 4), sometimes it won't even show the colorful screen (as it is showing for you).
I am now used to pay good money in chargers and cables, and never had such problem ever since.
E.g: a cable from Baseus (https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005002519021541.html) is a good proven one.